# Gmail labels - How to apply to POP3?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, pop3

I have created some filters in gmail with the intention to automatically move messages to folders in Windows Live Mail or any POP3 reader. My idea is to mark the messages with a different "label" in gmail and then use that label to create rules in the POP3 program. The problem is that I can´t find the label anywhere in the emails I receive in POP3 from gmail. I mean, the label is nowhere in the header so that the pop3 program can know it. Am I missing something or the "labels" are only useful in gmail itself? Is there a way of changing the subject of the message from "Xxxxx" to "[jokes] Xxxxxx" after it is assigned to that "label" (jokes) in gmail?

Comment: **Voters: Please don't move this to Web Applications.** It is about POP3 (readers), not about Gmail...

Answer (score 5):

> Am I missing something or the "labels" are only useful in gmail itself?

If you're using POP3 - Yep. AFAIK, you can leverage labels through IMAP only.